# nested structs and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am learning about nested structures and came across the following code:

```
// Stack.h

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

struct Stack{
    struct Link{
        void* data;
        Link* next;
        void initialize(void* dat, Link* nxt);
    }* head;
    void initialize();
    void push(void* dat);
    void* peek();
    void* pop();
    void cleanup();
};

#endif // STACK_H
```

the Link structure is within the scope of Stack and to access Link I would have to use Stack::Link.

I am a bit confused about the pointer head that is declared after the } to close the Link struct.

Does this mean that there is a Link pointer variable named head inside the Stack scope?

What is the effect of defining the head pointer as:

```
};
Link* head;
```

vs

```
}* head; //as per the code above?
```

Comment: Sidenote: do you *really* want to use a linked list for imlementing a stack? Seems wasteful.

Comment: I am just learning about C++ and that is what I have been using in my data structures and algorithms class

Comment: @H2CO3 how would you recommend to implement a stack?

Comment: In first place, `std::vector` can be used as a stack, so there's no practical need for an implementation. However, if you want to do it, you can use an array or an encapsulated `std::vector`. Since you would be inserting and deleting from the end only, that's `O(1)` in the case of an array and a vector. In contrast, traversing a link list then deleting from the end is `O(n)` (unless you were smart enough to insert to the head, i. e. use the list backwards). Furthermore, arrays and vectors use a contiguous block of memory, so they are more compact, and they also prevent you from

Comment: % from traversing pointers, thus decreasing the possibility for cache misses. I suggest you watch the talk dubbed "Why you should avoid link lists" by Bjarne Stroustrup, it's on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. Both declarations result in a `Stack::head` member of type `Stack::Link*`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that there is a `Link` pointer variable named head inside the `Stack` scope?

Yes, that's exactly right.

As to your second question, there is no semantic difference between the two styles of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a short hand for the semantic. like how we use `+=`.
And yes you have a local pointer variable.

```
struct Stack{
    struct Link{
        void* data;
        Link* next;
        void initialize(void* dat, Link* nxt);
    };

    Link* head;  //Same as code as in your program
    void initialize();
    void push(void* dat);
    void* peek();
    void* pop();
    void cleanup();
};
```